# AEM: How to dynamically get the current page path and pass it to the request parameter for drop down

Tags: content-management-system, aem

options=/bin/services/myservlet.GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES.json?locale='some_locale'

if I put locale=en-us it works fine,

How can I dynamically get the current page locale and pass it to the request parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your servlet requires locale as one of the parameters to retrieve dropdown values. I can think of 2 options to do this.

1. Invoke the servlet with $Path as one of the parameters. $Path will give you the complete page path, all the way till jcr:content. `options=/bin/services/myservlet.GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES.json?compNode=$PATH`.

In your servlet, construct page object using $PATH, then as `@jwepurchase` mentioned, get the locale using [page.getLanguage(false)](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getLanguage(boolean)).

```
String compNodePath = (String) request.getParameter("compNode");  
String pagePath = StringUtils.substringBefore(compNodePath, "jcr:content");  
PageManager pageMgr = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(PageManager.class);  
Page page = pageMgr.getContainingPage(pagePath);  
Locale pageLocale = page.getLanguage(false);
```

`getLanguage` will look for jcr:language property in currentpage or its ancestors. This property gets set when you set the Language field in page properties (advanced  tab) of your page(usually set in the root locale page) to an appropriate value. eg: If you set the language to english(us), jcr:language will be en_us.

2. Similar steps as option 1, if value in page property is not set, you can use [currentPage.getAbsoluteParent(DEPTH_VAL)](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getAbsoluteParent(int)) to retrieve the locale value. Not a recommended soln though.

Answer (score 0):

`com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page.getLanguage(false)` will return the value of the jcr:language property on the page or the first parent page where it is sent. Generally this isn't set on every page.

If you have included Adobe's global.jsp or used the `<cq:defineObjects/>` tag in your JSP, you should find that "currentPage" is already in scope, providing access to a Page object.

I generally have a custom taglib function to make it easier to access via EL. But as a scriptlet I expect the following would work:

`<%= ((Page)getPageContext().getAttribute("currentPage")).getLanguage(false)%>`

Comment: I guess you understood the OP's question wrong. The query was how to dynamically pass the locale to the servlet which provides the options for selection widget in the dialog.